# Are Baer Rings worth studying for significant modern progress in vNa's?

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I am wondering if Kaplansky's "Ring of Operators" is worth studying if I'm interested in functional analysis (more specifically von Neumann algebras).  Yes any vNa is a B. ring but my question is more if reading this book or studying this subject is fruitful for practical vNa research.  Do people who actually do research in vNa or C* algebras ever appeal to the more general structure of Baer rings?

In particular, do Baer rings play a significant role in the (modern) study of von Neumann algebras?

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm against this question being closed. That being said, the current title/question seems way too open to opinion, and maybe a bit argumentative. Perhaps you might consider the title "Do Baer rings play a significant role in the study of von Neumann algebras?" (or something similar), along the lines of your last sentence.

Comment: Also, just a curiosity. Is there an analogue to C* algebras similar to that between Baer Rings and vNa's? vNa's are a noncommutative generalization of measure theory and C* algebras are a sort of noncommutative topology, is there a corresponding algebraic structure that is more general for C*algebras the way Baer rings are ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is definitely no. Kaplansky's attemp to study von Neumann algebras from a completely algebraic point of view was a very interesting exercise, but it didn't really bear fruit. Until the 70s people were publishing papers showing that certain property occurred (or didn't) in an AW$^*$-algebra. These days, only a handful of people (mostly from those times) pay attention to AW$^*$-algebras. And I know of no instance where a paper in von Neumann algebras builds on something done on AW$^*$-algebras. Even if someone would prove the main open conjecture (that all AW$^*$-algebras are monotone complete), I don't think that would attract much attention.

Shorter answer: the whole Baer-AW$^*$ effort always played catchup to the theory of von Neumann algebras, and was eventually left in the dust.